# SQL statement error when UNION is used with aggregates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, union

I have this SQL I'm using with amazon redshift that errors out on the second select statement despite both queries being valid without a union:

```
select p.date,
       sum(p.pageviews) as "total_pageviews",
       sum(p.sessions)  as "total_sessions",
       l.location_id,
       p.brand_key
from public.local_site_sessions p, public.location_map l
where l.affiliate_id = p.affiliate_id
group by p.date, p.brand_key, l.location_id order by p.date

union

select g.date,
       g.sessions as "total_pageviews",
       g.pages_per_session as "total_sessions",
       g.location_id,
       brand_key
from public.ga_lead g
group by g.date, g.brand_key, g.location_id, g.sessions, g.pages_per_session    
order by g.date
```

The error says the second select statement is a syntax error? How can I correct this query?

Comment: Edit your question with the error message you're receiving?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4):

You don't need  group by for the second query  ..  you have not aggregated  function

```
select p.date, sum(p.pageviews) as "total_pageviews", sum(p.sessions) as "total_sessions",l.location_id, p.brand_key
FROM public.local_site_sessions p, public.location_map l
where l.affiliate_id = p.affiliate_id
group by p.date, p.brand_key, l.location_id 

union

select g.date, g.sessions , g.pages_per_session ,g.location_id, brand_key
FROM public.ga_lead g
```

And you should not use older implict join  based on where  use explicit join
If you need order by apply the order by at the last select  and you should not use alias for the second  select

```
select p.date, sum(p.pageviews) as "total_pageviews", sum(p.sessions) as "total_sessions",l.location_id, p.brand_key
FROM public.local_site_sessions p
INNER JOIN  public.location_map l ON  l.affiliate_id = p.affiliate_id
group by p.date, p.brand_key, l.location_id 

union

select g.date, g.sessions , g.pages_per_session ,g.location_id, brand_key
FROM public.ga_lead g
order by 1,4,5
```

Comment: i guess when we have add order by/group by's  in the queries of union we get this sorta syntax errors mostly because maybe order by becomes ambigous for columns as union together

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja   .  then order by in UNION should be applied  at the end  .. you comment is not clear  ..  anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just add an outside select to your initial union query

```
    Select * from
     ( Select.... union Select.... )
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting via console there might be cursor pointed to that exact syntax error like near `)` syntax the above was like an alternative i posted to run the query